# CI_JOB_DATA future dated rows

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

I have written an app engine calling CI CI_JOB_DATA. Everything works fine with the exception when there an employee has a future dated row in their JOB data.  Specifically, a termination row.

So, we are loading salary increases for all employees as of a certain date, let's say 03/12/2022. The process works fine for all employees who do not have a future dated record, but if an employee has a termination record for example 03/28/2022, the process gives me this error:

**Action is valid only if prior HR Status is Active or Empl Status is Retired or Terminated with Pay. (1000,972)**

So, the process is looking at this future dated row, when it should be looking at their JOB data as of 03/12/2022.

Anybody has this issue?

Comment: Probably a bit too late, but if you try to do something in between effdated rows, you have some validations like this. Are you trying to insert a new row in between?

Answer (score 1):

Try replicating the same scenario from the PIA. sometimes this may happen based on where the new row is inserted. sometimes, inserting the row literally before the termination row(even though the date is already before termination) will work.